# Black lines appearing on parts of model in Tabletop Simulator but not in Blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, export

[image]
The weird lines are visible in Tabletop simulator but not in Blender.

I tried triangulating and recalculating normals. Then I tried deleting the faces and remaking them, then triangulating and recalculating normals again.

I suspect I've have missed a step that I don't know exists.

[image]

Comment: Please use the Insert Image icon in your post in order to embed a screenshot or image (click the `Edit` link just below your post. Also please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to attach a blend file. This will ensure the persistence of the link. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Sorry for the error.